# In R, how to run R script for each Access file in a folder of Access files?

Tags: r

I have a bunch of files (in .accdb, they are MS Access files) that I pull into R, modify and format, and then convert to .xlsx files. However I have to manually operate my script each time by **entering the file name individually**. Is it possible to dynamically pull the name from my file folder and then run and output the files without having to do this manually?

For example, I have my file folder with the files: cat.accdb, dog.accdb, bird.accdb, etc. (the files names change and cannot be predicted sequentially), then I run the script in R that looks like:

1. import cat.accdb file from folder (this requires inputting the name of the file)
2. process cat.accdb file
3. convert to cat.xlsx file
4. output cat.xlsx file in my folder
5. repeat the sequence for the other .accdb files.

Again, my coding works fine, but is there some additional code I can add that can pull each file name directly from the file folder, run the code for each file, then output the excel file in the same folder without having to go in and copy the name manually?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

A generic solution
(so *better check before* submitting the whole set of candidate files to processing):

```
library(tools)
```

- define your function which takes in a filename (full file path), imports, processes and saves the processed data under identical filename *except* the extension:

```
workhorse_function <- \(ffp){
  ext  <-  file_ext(ffp)
  fn_wo_ext <- file_path_sans_ext(ffp)
  d <- rio::import(ffp) ## replace with importer of choice
  d_processed <- d ## replace with data processing
  rio::export( ## replace with exporter of choice
         x = d_processed,
         file = sprintf('%s.csv', ## replace with appropriate extension
                        fn_wo_ext
                        ) 
       )  
}
```

- store names of candidate files:

```
the_file_names <- list.files(pattern = '\\.xlsx$', ## replace with appropriate patt
                             recursive = TRUE,
                             full.names = TRUE)
```

- run your function on candidate files:

```
Map(the_file_names, f = \(file_name) workhorse_function(file_name))
```